# Case Study on Enterprise Architecture

Tags: togaf

I was given an assignment to find and analyze a case about enterprise architecture. I was given an example [this](https://hbr.org/2007/07/too-far-ahead-of-the-it-curve) from Harvard business review. I've searched for some case study but haven't been able to find a good one. Can anyone tell me about or give me link to some famous enterprise architecture problem of a specific company or related case to the above link? I just got into the ea world and haven't fully understood everything.

Answer (score 3):

The question is tagged TOGAF, and the Open Group has some case studies on their site ([TOGAF Case Studies](http://www.opengroup.org/public/arch/p4/cases/case_intro.htm). These are not necessarily academic quality references, however.

Case studies for the federal enterprise architecture framework (FEAF) may be found at [FEAF Success Stories](https://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/E-Gov/EA-Success). These case studies are also of questionable academic quality, and frequently demonstrate compliance with a mandate rather than true EA benefits.

Comment: FEAF Success Stories- link is no more valid

Comment: @Vishnu, I have no idea if the complete usurpation of the whitehouse.gov site by the inauguration announcement will be lifted, or if the new administration no longer cares about an federal architecture. I am sorry the link broke; one might have expected the government to maintain information about its information strategy...